# Se elimina el valor de variable al pasarlo de js a php

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, laravel-5, array

Estoy haciendo un envio por ajax desde js a php.

Estoy haciendo un envio de un array de objetos utilizando angular, aqui mi codigo.

```
$scope.updateRecipe = function()
{
    //Se hace petición ajax para agregar el producto
    $http(
    {
        //Se elige el metodo de la consulta
        method: 'POST',

        //Cabecera
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('input[name="_token"]').val()},

        //Data
        data:$scope.arrayObject,

        //Se ingeresa la ruta de la consulta
        url: './ruta'
    })

    //Si hay una respuesta positiva
    .then(function (response)
    {
      //Respuesta
    });
```

};

El array es el siguiente

```
[
 {"idItem":68,"item":"salsa piña","quantity":1,"unit":"Gramo","idProduct":80,"deletable":false,"isNew":false}
 ,{"idItem":71,"item":"salsa mostaza","quantity":1,"unit":"Gramo","idProduct":80,"deletable":false,"isNew":false}
 ,{"idItem":79,"item":"","quantity":2,"unit":"Kilogramo","idProduct":0,"deletable":false,"isNew":true}
]
```

El problema, es que cuando llega a php se muestra de la siguiente manera

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [idItem] => 68
        [item] => salsa piña
        [quantity] => 1
        [unit] => Gramo
        [idProduct] => 80
        [deletable] => 
        [isNew] => 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [idItem] => 71
        [item] => salsa mostaza
        [quantity] => 1
        [unit] => Gramo
        [idProduct] => 80
        [deletable] => 
        [isNew] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [idItem] => 79
        [item] => 
        [quantity] => 2
        [unit] => Kilogramo
        [idProduct] => 0
        [deletable] => 
        [isNew] => 1
)
```

Desaparece los valores de algunas variables...

Saben porque puede pasar esto

Comment: ¿Qué valores desaparecen? Ten en cuenta que en PHP, `false`, `""` y `null` son "equivalentes" aunque no sean lo mismo (puedes ver las tablas de comparación flexible en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/types.comparisons.php)).

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, Exactamente este era mi error, ya que ignoraba eso de php, te lo agradezco, de igual forma uan respuesta tambien me ayudo a solucionar el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal, cuando serializas y deserializas datos debe codificarlos correctamente.

En Javascript tienes las funciones [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) y [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) para serializar y deserializar respectivamente.

En PHP tienes las funciones [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) y [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) como contraparte.

Antes de enviar tu array por ajax debes prepararlo:

```
let datos = JSON.stringify($scope.arrayObject);
...
    Cabecera
    headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('input[name="_token"]').val()},

    //Data
    data:datos,
...
```

En PHP recibes el JSON codificado y los debes decodificar:

```
... 
$datos_en_php = json_decode($datos_desde_ajax); 
echo $datos_en_php[0]->idItem . '<br /> . $datos_en_php[0]->item;
```

A su vez al enviar tus respuestas desde PHP a Javascript utilizas las otras dos funciones:

```
$resultado = json_encode($algun_resultado);
echo $resultado;
```

En Javascript recibes la respuesta y debes parsearla:

```
...
.then($data){
    let datos = JSON.parse($data);
    console.log(datos.alguna_propiedad);   
}
```

Espero te sirva.